# Terminating a script execute with user1 without loop

Tags: bash

This is an example of My script. How do i terminate it after it execute. it looping.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Checks root permission
if [ $(id -u) != "0" ]; then
   echo "You must be the superuser to run this script" >&2
   su -c "$0 $@"
fi

echo "welcome to script"
cd /var/app
cp index.html index10.html

su john -c 'command1 && command2'

if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
cp index10.html index.html
echo "script exit"
else
echo "error"
fi
exit 1
```

I believe the when the script executes with user john. the su -c "$0 $@" runs it with root. and when the su command is done.. script continues. Is there any way i restrict script without executing and terminate with echo "scriptexit".  I mean without removing the su -c "$0 $@" ? I know if script executed as root user then it will fine.

Answer (score 0):

Put an `exit` after the first `su` command (inside the `if` block).